# Create files from textfile and fill it with a short text string?

Tags: command-line

I´m in OS X terminal and trying to do the following:

I have a .txt file with lines of text. 
I want every single line to become a file.

This I have managed by doing: 
cat file.txt | xargs touch

This produces my list of files but I need them to have some kind of content, not blank.

Can someone help me with a command that produces the files from the list with a single line of text inside every file?

Just like the command echo 'Hello, world.' >foo.txt creates text in foo.txt but with my scenario as described. 
Is it possible?

Thanks in advance!

/Niklas

Comment: Your description is not clear. What’s the content of the source file? Is every line with both file name and file content?

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. A simple approach:

```
echo 'Hello, world.' > foo.txt
< file.txt xargs -L 1 cp foo.txt
rm foo.txt
```

The `cat` command is vastly overused;
when you see `cat filename | command`,
you can change it to `command < filename` or,
equivalently, `< filename command`. 
The `-L 1` option to `xargs` tells it
to read only one line from `file.txt` at a time;
so, if `file.txt` contains `file1` and `file2` (on separate lines),
then `xargs` will run

```
cp foo.txt file1
cp foo.txt file2
```

I presume the rest is self-explanatory. 
If you want to put this all on one line, just join the lines with `&&`:

```
echo 'Hello, world.' > foo.txt  &&  xargs -L 1 cp foo.txt < file.txt  &&  rm foo.txt
```

I moved the `< file.txt` to the end of the `xargs` command,
which is where people usually put it.

#### 2. More flexible

You will probably want to do something more complex and sophisticated
than writing the same single line to each file. 
This command:

```
xargs sh -c 'for f do echo "Hello, world." > "$f"; done' sh < file.txt
```

passes the filenames to an invocation of the shell (`sh`),
which can then do anything to the named file (referenced as `"$f"`)
that you could do from the shell prompt. 
And, obviously, with this method,
you don’t need to create and delete a temporary file.

#### 3. Without using `xargs`

You can simplify the above to

```
while IFS= read -r f
do
    echo 'Hello, world.' > "$f"
done < file.txt
```

which is essentially the same as the previous answer,
except this time the shell reads the `file.txt` file,
so you don’t need `xargs`.